# How create Abaqus RSG gui builder that shows material property

Tags: python, user-interface, abaqus

I want to create a RSG gui builder that can show the material property. The following code can do such a thing.

```
from odbAccess import openOdb
odb_file_path=r'your_path\file.odb'
odb = openOdb(odb_file_path)
instance = odb.rootAssembly.instances['PART-1-1']
material_name = instance.elements[0].sectionCategory.name[8:-2]
density=odb.materials[material_name].density.table[0][0]) #density
odb.materials[material_name].userMaterial  #user material parameters
```

I'd like to create a plug-in for this code as I need to use it a lot. But I have difficulty figuring out the meanings of boxes in 'Combo Box'.
[image]

I was wondering what is the difference between these two 'Keyword', and how should I achieve my goal (show material property with really simple GUI)?

#################### **update**

I use a simple function to test the 'Combo Box'. I am not expecting this function to show the material property, but hope to see no errors...

```
def show_material(material):
    print material
```

Comment: What the error says is that your function "material" does not have a keyword argument "keys". You can configure your function in kernel tab. I would recommend naming everything with unique names so there is no confusion.

Comment: @UN4 If I use a very simple function _**'def material(self, materialNow):
 print materialNow'**_ The software still throws me an error _**'got an unexpected keyword argument'**_ I really don't understand how this combo box works

Comment: your function name should not be the same as variable names. The function should like this **def your_function_name(keys,material): print keys, material**

Comment: @UN4 It still doesn't work even if the **function_name** is changed. The thing here is that it's not clear how this **Combo Box** works?

Comment: Can you show me the whole code? I can then perhaps comment better.

Comment: @UN4 I add a simple function. But even this simple function doesn't work

Comment: The error is correct, you need two variables in the function as combo box passes two keywords. From your screenshot **materials, keys**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is just a basic misunderstanding of python syntax.

Here is example of your case:
[image]

The Kernel is defined like this:
[image]

if in you highlight title in the GUI tree you can select **Show dialog in test mode**. Then when you click **OK** on your plugin you see this message:

[image]

this is important as it shows what keywords have to be accepted in your function! You see that I have already defined my kernel function to accept **materials** and **keys**, therefore, no further steps are necessary and i can test my plugin by disabling **Show dialog in test mode**.

[image]

as you can see from the figure above the plugin works.

Things to note:

- your function has to accept all the keyword you are passing to it
- your function name should not be the same as any of your keywords
- your module name should be unique and never used in other kernels